# Values of the j-function

Tags: nt.number-theory

In general, how do you compute the algebraic values of the modular j-function at quadratic imaginary points? (In other words, how do you compute the algebraic values of singular moduli?)

For instance, the Mathematica website (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/j-Function.html) gives the standard nine integral examples that result when the class number $h_k=1$, but then it gives 18 examples for when the class number is 2 without any specific references. How does one compute these? More importantly, can you also do it for higher degree cases? Or even just find the defining degree-$h_k$ polynomial?

Answer (score 11):

One crude  but effective method is to compute all the h conjugates a<sub>j</sub> numerically to high precision, from which you can find the polynomial Π(x-a<sub>j</sub>) they are the roots of using the fact that it has integral coefficients, (h=class number, and the values a<sub>j</sub> are the values of j at the imaginary quadratic integers with the same discriminant.)

Alternatively see the paper [On singular moduli](http://www.reference-global.com/doi/abs/10.1515/crll.1985.355.191) by Gross and Zagier, which gives an explicit expression for the values of j as products of many small algebraic integers.

Comment: In the case of using *Mathematica*, I guess that would be first computing the values of the j-function (which IIRC is expressible as ratios of powers of theta functions) numerically and then subjecting them to Recognize[] I suppose. (I don't know which package you should be loading for this in $VersionNumber >=6, but in $VersionNumber < 6 it's NumberTheory`Recognize`)

Answer (score 3):

In case the Gross-Zagier paper doesn't meet your needs, you can also refer to the following

1. Harold Baier [Efficient computation
   of singular moduli](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.111.5103)
2. Noriko Yui 
       [On The Singular Values Of Weber
       Modular Functions](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.42.730)

and of course David Cox's book [Primes of the form $x^2 + Ny^2$, Section 3.12](http://www.cs.amherst.edu/~dac/primes.html)

The bad thing about the j-function is that it is a level 1 modular function so the coefficients of its defining polynomial are going to explode with increasing degree.  Its easier to compute the singular moduli using a modular function of some higher level (e.g. Weber func has level 48) as demonstrated in the papers mentioned above as well in Cox's book.